# Problem with GLM regressor in reusing it for different input data

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, gaussian-process, machine-learning-model

Hie, I have trained a GLM model with 3 output as target. Then I save the model info in terms of params and family with pickle. Now I load that model with different input dataset to predict its output but I am getting error as "**Gaussian model is not callable**". Please suggest me something to solve this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKMPA.png)

I am expecting some solution to this problem